# When I put on dedicated GPU to my PC it displays black screen

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, ubuntu-14.04

I am posting this question and answer for future use of myself and people who face the same problem.

Problem: I need to install Nvidia Tesla K40 GPU on my PC ubuntu 14.04. However when I put GPU on PC then turn on, all I get is black screen. I figured it out the cause was my bios was loading the dedicated GPU(Tesla K40) as primary GPU instead of the onboard intel GPU. Since Tesla K40 is only for compute and not for display I was getting black screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell BIOS to load onboard GPU as primary display instead of dedicated GPU.

Go to *BIOS*-> *Advanced Mode* -> *System Agents* -> *Graphics Settings* -> *Primary Display*. In my case Primary Display was set to *PCIE* mode which which was loading the Tesla K40 dedicated GPU as primary. Since Tesla K40 is only for compute and not for display, I was getting a black screen. Setting it to *iGPU* will load the onboard GPU as primary displayer.